# SQL Server 2008 R2 update while loop with temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I'm having difficulties in updating a table (say TableA).
Currently I'm using 2 loops.

```
1st Loop is based on the data from temp table named : ##tempTableB
2nd Loop is based on the data from temp table named : ##tempTableC.
```

How do update TableA with a script sample like this.

```
declare @amount money;
declare @i int =1;
declare @total int;

declare @j int = 1;
declare @total2 int;

declare @numberid nvarchar(14);
declare @num int;
declare @principal money;
declare @margin money;
declare @insurance money;

select @numberid=numberid,@amount=amount from ##temptableB
set @total = @rowcount; -- 48 rows result

while @i <= @total
begin

    select @num=num,
    @principal=principal,
    @margin=margin,
    @insurance=insurance from ##tempTableC

    set @total2 = @rowcount;-- 48 rows result

    while @j <=total2
    begin

    update tableA set
    payedprincipal=@principal,payed_margin=@margin,payed_insurance=@insurance` 
    where numberid=@numberid
    set @j=@j+1
    end

set @i=@i+1
end
```

Comment: You realise that @numberid is just a single random record from ##temptableB? Did you know you can `UPDATE` multiple records in one table based off multiple records in other tables in one single `UPDATE` statement without loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a direct update script that can update table B or C based on values from table A. Here's a sample you can run in a new query window that simply updates values based on a `JOIN` between the tables that are involved:

**SETUP TEMP TABLES**

```
declare @tempA table (id int, val int)
declare @tempB table (id int, val int)

-- Source table
insert into @tempA (id, val) values (1,100)
insert into @tempA (id, val) values (2,200)
insert into @tempA (id, val) values (3,300)
insert into @tempA (id, val) values (4,400)

-- table that requires updates
insert into @tempB (id, val) values (1,0)
insert into @tempB (id, val) values (2,0)
insert into @tempB (id, val) values (3,0)
insert into @tempB (id, val) values (4,0)

-- output initial values 
Select * from @tempA
Select * from @tempB
```

Then run an update script to update the `val` column of `@tempB` with the values from `@tempA` where the `id` columns match:

```
Update b 
SET val = a.val
FROM @tempB b 
     INNER JOIN @tempA a on a.id = b.id

-- output the updated values
Select * from @tempA
Select * from @tempB
```

Comment: thanks for tips & for quick reply. Although this isn't perfectly fit. actually this is a simple version of my Bulk Payment processor on an installment schedule. in this case is the trans record would be on ##tempTableB and Inst Schedule on ##tempTableB.
need to process trans record one by one because there will be div portion of installment based on amount on ##temptableB.
the payment is handled and separated sequentially based on portion off insurance,margin,and principal. excess payment after division will be store to next row. with set based i think will not suitable.

Comment: i accept this as alternative solution. thanks anyway.